# Install-WindowsFeature fails to find source on first run, succeeds the second time

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

Background: I am trying to install Active Directory Domain Services inside of a Virtualbox instance of Windows Server 2012 R2, and have been unable to get the features installed via the GUI or Powershell in a normal scenario.

When I run `Install-WindowsFeature AD-Domain-Services -IncludeManagementTools -Source @("wim:e:\sources\install.wim:2")`, eventually the command returns at 68% stating that it could not find the installation sources. However, on subsequent runs, the command succeeds and ADDS is available along with the associated cmdlets and management tools. I cannot find a reason to this rhyme for the life of me, what could be the issue? I have tried several forms of the command above, including specifying `E:\sources\sxs` directly as well as omitting the `-Source` parameter entirely.

While this does install ADDS on the target, I consider it a workaround having to run `Install-WindowsFeature` twice, and would like to figure out how to find the root cause of the initial command failing. Also note that if I don't mount the installation ISO, it doesn't grab the sources from Windows Update, which is ideally how I'd like to install additional features.

*EDIT* The version is Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Server 2012 R2, you may use Add-WindowsFeature instead.

```
Get-WindowsFeature
Add-WindowsFeature -AD-Domain-Services -IncludeManagementTools
```

Comment: It still yields the same error, which stinks because I had a glimmer of hope that it was going to work for a second: `Use the "source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077. Error: 0x800f0906

Comment: It is a core installation? Which edition, standard or datacenter?

Comment: Standard edition. I've updated the question to contain this information.

Comment: When you do the Get-WindowsFeature query, does the target role shows up as Installed, Available, or Removed?

To specify a source, try using Add-WindowsFeature -AD-Domain-Services -IncludeManagementTools -Source WIM:E:\Sources\Install.wim:2

Comment: It shows up as Removed, which I believe is because the local sources were removed. However, I'm specifying the source as stated in the question, and this is when I'm running into the run-it-twice-to-succeed issue. If I don't specify the source, it does not look at Windows Update, which would be preferable for installing the feature.

Comment: *Just* ran in the exact situation. Try disabling your WSUS server, because the feature request fail to connect to Windows Update.